# How to repeat a many-to-many relationship in Django?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have these models in my Django app:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class AnimalList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    list = models.ManyToManyField(Amimal)
```

I want to add the same pokemon to the same list twice:

```
>>> animal = Animal.objects.create(name='milla')
>>> user = User.objects.create(username='user')
>>> list = AnimalList.objects.create(user=user)
>>> list.list.add(animal)
>>> list.list.add(animal)
>>> animal.save()
```

The animal is added only once, though:

```
>>> list.list.all()
<QuerySet [<Animal: Animal object (3)>]>
```

I expected that, [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) is explicit that

> Adding a second time is OK, it will not duplicate the relation:

Yet, I do want to repeat the animals.

How could I do that? Is it possible by using `ManyToManyField`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not repeat these relationships because Django applies a `UniqueConstrant` to many-to-many relationships. My solution was to add another table that referenced the animals:

```
class AnimalListItem(models.Model):
    animal = models.ForeignKey(Animal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class AnimalList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    list_items1 = models.ManyToManyField(AnimalListItem)
```

After that, every time I wanted to add an animal to a list, I had to create a list item first, pointing to the animal, then add this list item to the list column.

There are other possible solutions as well. For example, the [`through` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) from `ManyToManyField` disables any default constraints that would be added to the relationship table. Or you could [set `db_constraint` to `False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.db_constraint) without `through`.

However, those were not solutions to me because, as [the documentation states](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/):

> If the custom through table defined by the intermediate model does not enforce uniqueness on the (model1, model2) pair, allowing multiple values, the remove() call will remove all intermediate model instances

I needed to remove only one instance at a time, so removing all of them would not be feasible.